# running read csv from qpython and assign to table

Tags: kdb

I would like to run the following q code in python:

```
table: ("ISI"; enlist ",") 0:`data.csv
```

I am starting with exploring qpython as its easier to use in Windows for now (compared to pyq) and would like to do the following:

```
q = qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000)
q.sync('table: ("ISI"; enlist ",") 0:`data.csv')
```

Is something like this possible or do I need to use pyq in the future when its stable for Windows? The examples I have seen for q.sync are queries and functions that take a list of parameters rather than directly running code in the q environment. I would like to make sure I am not missing some other functionality that I can use for my current task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to access a file you have to use its file handle which is of the form `` `:data.csv `` (notice the colon at the start), instead of a symbol which is what you are using. You can use `hsym` to turn a symbol into a file handle.

You should also check that the file is in the same working directory as the q process, using `\dir` in the q process on Windows, otherwise you will need to adapt your file handle to point to the correct location

```
q)hsym `data.csv
`:data.csv
```

With a file data.csv that has contents:

```
id,sym,val
1,APPL,50
2,GOOG,100
```

Running the same command that you did but using the file handle:

```
In:   q.sync('table: ("ISI"; enlist ",") 0: `:data.csv')
```

or

```
In:   q.sync('table: ("ISI"; enlist ",") 0:hsym `qpython.csv')
```

Checking the resulting variable using qpython:

```
In:   q.sync('table')
Out:  rec.array([(1, b'APPL',  50), (2, b'GOOG', 100)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('sym', 'S4'), ('val', '<i4')])
```

Checking in the q process

```
q)table
id sym  val
-----------
1  APPL 50
2  GOOG 100
```